# Why is getWindow() saying it can't find symbol?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm new to stack overflow but I kinda need help with this one. I'm trying to build an OSRS client with openOSRS however I'm running into an issue.

I'm getting the error message:

"error: cannot find symbol
JSObject.getWindow(var14).call("zap", (Object[])null); // L: 2217"

```
                if (Login_isUsernameRemembered) { // L: 2190
                    WorldMapSectionType.clientPreferences.rememberedUsername = Login.Login_username; // L: 2191
                } else {
                    WorldMapSectionType.clientPreferences.rememberedUsername = null; // L: 2194
                }

                class23.savePreferences(); // L: 2196
                staffModLevel = ((AbstractSocket)var1).readUnsignedByte(); // L: 2197
                playerMod = ((AbstractSocket)var1).readUnsignedByte() == 1; // L: 2198
                localPlayerIndex = ((AbstractSocket)var1).readUnsignedByte(); // L: 2199
                localPlayerIndex <<= 8; // L: 2200
                localPlayerIndex += ((AbstractSocket)var1).readUnsignedByte(); // L: 2201
                field673 = ((AbstractSocket)var1).readUnsignedByte(); // L: 2202
                ((AbstractSocket)var1).read(var2.array, 0, 1); // L: 2203
                var2.offset = 0; // L: 2204
                ServerPacket[] var5 = WorldMapRegion.ServerPacket_values(); // L: 2205
                int var19 = var2.readSmartByteShortIsaac(); // L: 2206
                if (var19 < 0 || var19 >= var5.length) { // L: 2207
                    throw new IOException(var19 + " " + var2.offset);
                }

                packetWriter.serverPacket = var5[var19]; // L: 2208
                packetWriter.serverPacketLength = packetWriter.serverPacket.length; // L: 2209
                ((AbstractSocket)var1).read(var2.array, 0, 2); // L: 2210
                var2.offset = 0; // L: 2211
                packetWriter.serverPacketLength = var2.readUnsignedShort(); // L: 2212

                try {
                    Client var14 = class1.client; // L: 2214
                    JSObject.getWindow(var14).call("zap", (Object[])null); // L: 2217
                } catch (Throwable var20) { // L: 2220
                }

                loginState = 16; // L: 2221
            }
```

Comment: We don't know what `JSObject` is so we can't tell if has `getWindow` method. To get proper answer please provide proper [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: Also if this code depends on some libraries please provide that info (and add library tag to the question -just like you did for `java` tag - so people who are familiar with it and are observing that tag could be informed about your question).

Comment: my bad, im new to this :)

Comment: Is that [jdk.jsobject.JSObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html)? If so, it should have a static `getWindow()` method (though deprecated in Java 10). And it takes a bit to learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please don’t despair.

Comment: @OleV.V. it is "jdk.jsobject.JSObject" however I cannot find a static getWindow() method.

Answer (score 0):

This is not my home field, so there’s a bit of guessing in this. I will delete this answer if I discover my guess was wrong.

`netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow()` takes an argument of type `Applet`. You are passing a `Client` to it. Unless `Client` is a subclass of `Applet`, this will not work. Where I am unsure is whether this would give you the error message that you quote. If so, the message doesn’t seem very helpful.

Link: [documentation of `JSObject.getWindow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html#getWindow(java.applet.Applet))